# How to inherits resources configuration files in child modules with Maven

Tags: maven

I'm facing a problem of organization with Maven, as I'm learning struts through a book, I want to organize as follows :

```
Project Parent (pom packaging)
   pom.xml(packaging:pom)  
   src
         main
              resources -> Struts.xml

   child-a(chapter1)
        pom.xml(packaging:war)  
        src
            main
                 resources -> none
```

When I run `mvn package` or `resources:resources` from child-a in the target resources there is no struts.xml packaged and inherited from the pom project.

Is there any workaround or configuration to add in order to make this happen?

Comment: If the configuration in your case the `Structs.xm` belongs to `child-a` that put it into child-a and not somewhere else apart from that a parent will never have a kind of code nor resources at all...

Comment: Fair enough, but the idea is to extend by adding other modules (child-b, c etc, ) and each child would be a dependent struts application with this very same config.